# gtk2 expose-event not working with destroy

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I'm on a project using gtk2. There is a window which contains some animations.
I followed some tutorials, but I've reached a dead end:

```
static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget)
{
 gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
 return true;
}

static void paint (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
{
    cairo_t *cr;
    cr = gdk_cairo_create (gtk_widget_get_window(widget));
    printf("this is numb ");

    cairo_stroke (cr);
    cairo_destroy (cr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
argC = argc; argV = argv;

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();

  GtkWidget *button;

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();

  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                    G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "mazas demo");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 600, 400);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);

  g_timeout_add(1, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) window);  

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  g_signal_connect_after (G_OBJECT(window),"expose-event",
                        G_CALLBACK(paint), window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get stuck calling `static void paint` and when I try exiting the program on display the terminal says:

```
$ Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ 2 is now mostly obsolete. If you're learning GTK+, learn GTK+ 3.

As for your problem, the `paint` function should return a `gboolean` to say if the event needs to be propagated. As you handled it, you're supposed to return `FALSE`. `FALSE` (in uppercase) is `gboolean`. For that same reason, `time_handler` should probably return `TRUE`, not `true`. But you didn't even put your includes, so `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` is missing, and `true` is not defined either unless you `#include <stdbool.h>` anyway.

You're also calling `g_timeout_add` with a 1 milliseconds interval, which is too small, as I doubt your screen is able to display images at 100Hz frequency. You also are leaking memory has you have duplicated this line:

```
darea = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
```

Next, you forgot to put your drawing area inside your window. You should add:

```
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);
```

Next, you should connect to the expose event of the drawing area (as I supose that's where you want to paint), not the window one:

```
g_signal_connect_after (G_OBJECT(window),"expose-event",
                        G_CALLBACK(paint), darea);
```